# When is this lock-then-lock-again refactor a bad idea?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I've two sibling classes, `A` and `B`, and I want to refactor them so that `A` is the parent of `B`, so `B` can share `A`'s code. But this refactor would mean, for one key function, locking a mutex twice instead of once. What reasons are there not to?

**Class A**

```
class A{
     std::map<std::string, int> values;
     std::mutex mutex;
 public:
     //init and access functions elided

     void foo(std::string key, int v){
         auto i = values.find(key);
         if(i == values.end())return; //Actually report error
         {
             std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
             i->second = v;
         }
     }
};
```

**Class B**

```
class B{
    std::map<std::string, int> values;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > history;
    std::mutex mutex;
public:
    //init and access functions elided

    void foo(std::string key, int v){
        auto i = values.find(key);
        if(i == values.end())return; //Actually report error
        auto i2 = history.find(key);
        if(i2 == history.end())return; //Actually report error
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            i->second = v;
            i2->second.push_back(v);
        }
    }
 };
```

The alternative to class B that I'd like to write is:

```
class C:public A{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > history;
public:
    //init and access functions elided

    void foo(std::string key, int v){
        A::foo(key,v);
        auto i2 = history.find(key);
        if(i2 == history.end())return; //Actually report error
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            i2->second.push_back(v);
        }
    }
 };
```

The access functions also use the mutex, to lock their reads. For the purpose of this question assume `foo()` gets called a lot more than any other function in these classes. We can also assume all calls to `foo()` are serialized; the mutex is there for other threads that use the access functions.

Q. Splitting one mutex lock into two locks done in serial cannot add any new deadlock potential?

Q. Is there a bigger code smell from code duplication with class A and class B, or from "hiding" the extra mutex lock in the base class call?

Q. Is the extra overhead of locking twice going to be trivial compared to the other actions I am doing in `foo()`? I.e. I'm guessing that inserts into maps and vectors takes at least 10 times as long as locking a mutex.

Q. `class C` now allows a read of `values` that is out of sync with a read of `history` (i.e. if another thread grabbed the lock in the middle of `C::foo()`). If that turns out to be a problem, is going back to "duplicate the code in class A and B" the only design choice?

Comment: IMO, The biggest problem you raised is the final one.  If the data is inconsistent between `A::foo` and `i2->second.push_back(v)` then it's wrong and you're going to run into a race condition.  And there simply is not a way to do this using `A::foo` and keeping to a single lock (unless you're using a recursive mutex and you lock the entire call.)

Comment: That redundant opening brace on a line after an `if` is confusing ... the `return` isn't obvious (y u hate whitespace?) and at first glance it looks like the mutex lock is taken if the condition is true

Comment: Can users call `A::foo` directly? If yes, then you can already get a read of `values` that is out of sync with `history` because they can change independently.

Comment: Fine-grained locking like this usually doesn't work.  It all rather depends on what *else* you do with that `history` member.  Just returning its content in another member function already creates a stale view, one that isn't different from the race you created with the refactoring.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Is the brace redundant? I put braces around to show the scope of the lock, and so the lock isn't held during any code that comes after that block.  (I see my code has been edited to indent the locked scope; I haven't been doing that to differentiate it, and now it does look more confusing to me; but I don't know if your comment was before or after that edit!)

Comment: @DarrenCook, but there is no code after the block, so it's redundant. The lock would get released at the end of the function. (My comment came after the edit, but I would have found an unindented block _even more confusing_, if you add braces so you can control the scope of the lock and have it released at a particular point, then damn well indent the block to show at a glance where the scope ends!) I find your use of whitespace (or lack of it)  in the original pre-edit question very unhelpful to someone reading the code.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Whitespace decisions quickly get subjective, so I'm not going to argue that, but I will argue that it is good to always define the scope of a lock explicitly. (In the actual code I *do* have code, some log lines, that comes afterwards.)

Comment: But the end of a function _does_ define it explicitly :) if there are other lines in your real code that's a good reason to limit the scope. And it is subjective, but I do find `if(lotsoftextruntogether)return;` followed by a brace to be visually ambiguous, text at the end of a line, especially a conditional, is easy to skip, so the `return` is not visually distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this alternative, which adds a `foo_impl` function that returns the lock, so it can be re-used in `C::foo`:

```
class A
{
  std::map<std::string, int> values;
  std::mutex mutex;
public:
  //init and access functions elided

  void foo(std::string key, int v)
  {
    foo_impl(key, v);
  }

protected:
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> foo_impl(std::string key, int v)
  {
    auto i = values.find(key);
    if (i == values.end()) return {}; //Actually report error
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    i->second = v;
    return lock;
  }
};

class C : public A
{
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > history;
public:
  //init and access functions elided

  void foo(std::string key, int v)
  {
    auto i2 = history.find(key);
    if (i2 == history.end()) return; //Actually report error
    if (auto lock = A::foo_impl(key,v))
      i2->second.push_back(v);
  }
};
```

This ensures the updates to `A::values` and `C::history` are done under a single lock, so `A::values` cannot get updated again between the two locks in your original `C::foo`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why you think it's necessary to lock twice, this seem like what you want to do?

```
class A{
  std::map<std::string, int> values;
  std::mutex mutex;

protected:
  void foo_unlocked(std::string key, int v){
    auto i = values.find(key);
    if(i != values.end())
      i->second = v;
  }
};

class C:public A{
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > history;
public:
  //init and access functions elided

  void foo(std::string key, int v){
    auto i2 = history.find(key);
    if(i2 == history.end())
      return; //Actually report error

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    i2->second.push_back(v);
    foo_unlocked(key, v);  // do the operation in A but unlocked...
 }
```

};

Comment: This does `values.find(key)` while holding the lock, the original doesn't. Maybe that doesn't matter, but I assumed that was intentional and done to avoid holding the look during a potentially slow lookup.

Comment: It's a trivial task to refactor that out methinks..?

Comment: Yes, exactly what Jonathon said: code (such as the lookup) is not under the lock, following the principle of only lock for the minimum period you need.

Comment: It also breaks `A::foo[_unlocked]` entirely, since it is no longer protected at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, that's the whole point, it's *unlocked*, it's indicated as such in the method name, it's also protected, hence not part of the public interface - that's how it's supposed to work. You can still have a public `foo()` that's uses the *same* lock...

Comment: @Nim: Right, so that should go into the answer! Otherwise you entirely changed the OP's public interface.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, now we're splitting hairs methinks, I would hope the OP is smart enough to figure out the *pattern* here rather than use the code verbatim... I have no inclination to regurgitate his code in full...